# how to import hotmail contacts in java

Tags: java, hotmail

I need to import Hotmail contacts to my website in java, If any body have a detailed steps to make this or any one use Windows Live SDK to do similar task I will appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Windows Live Contacts API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463979.aspx). I think the section you need is: [Retrieving Contacts from Windows Live Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463933.aspx).

Comment: thanx dogban, but can you explaim in detail how to use this API in java in more details.